# Deleting from a Linked List

Tags: java, linked-list, nodes

I am writing a program to be a dictionary. In the program you can add and delete words, and print the current and deleted words. My problem is in my delete method, apparently it is deleting words properly but it is not making a linked list storing those deleted word to then print them. Therefore, it only prints the last word i deleted instead of all the words i've deleted. Here is the method:

```
public void delete(String b) 
{
    WordMeaningNode current = this.list;
    WordMeaningNode previous = null;
    WordMeaningNode temp;

    //While list is empty, return.
    if (this.list == null) 
    {
        return;
    }

    // While it is not empty..
    while (current != null) 
    {
        if (current.word.getWord().equalsIgnoreCase(b))
        {
            if (current == this.list)
            {

                this.list = this.list.next;
            } 
            else 
            {

                previous.next = current.next;
            }

            temp = current;
            del = temp;
            current.next = null;
            return;
        }

        previous = current;
        current = current.next;
    }
}
```

Can anybody see where my mistake is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what `del` is, but assuming it is a node in your deleted words linked list, all your doing is assigning the deleted word to del in `del = temp`. If you want to add it onto the del linked list you have to create a new node and add it on for example...

```
WordMeaningNode newDelNode;
newDelNode = temp;
del.next = temp;
```

something like that... I'm not entirely sure because it is a little difficult to read your code.